# Should Application Users and Administrators be in Different Database Tables?

Tags: database, architecture, frontend, backend

Wondering what the architecture best practices is. I've seen in some ecommerce codebases that customers and back-end users are in separate tables. I assume this is for security reasons.. but the simplicity of the 1 table to rule them all seems so alluring. 1 list to view them all, 1 add/edit/remove process to change em.

Recommendations appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the System we are talking here, for example in enterprise levels system which uses SOA patterns , it may connect to different central system even to authenticate users ( LDAP or direct database base etc ), where different kinds of systems/applications connect to a single authenticating and authorization module ( or service ).

In a enterprise level system I have worked with , we have kept users in a separate table while administrators in a separate table, so we can have clear table relationship for users separately and administrators separately,for example users may have joint account facility while administrator are not having such business related functionality and etc.

However, simple system other than mentioned above may use single authentication module for this purpose and it may use single table to keep both users and administrators  with a column to have user type for differentiation.

Also I don't think these kinds of users/administrators separation may not be solely for security purpose but may have business/domain purposes as mentioned above.

Hope this gave some idea to your question.